# Ensure unique username

Tags: asp.net, sql, t-sql, asp.net-membership

Asp.net membership 2.0.

I want to update the username in table aspnet_user, the best way is to update the table directly.

```
UPDATE aspnet_Users SET UserName = @UserName,LoweredUserName = LOWER( @UserName) 
WHERE UserName = @CurrentUname
```

How to ensure it is unique?

Thanks,

**UPDATE:** `If not exist (select UserName from aspnet_Users)
Begin
UPDATE aspnet_Users SET UserName = @UserName,LoweredUserName = LOWER( @UserName)

WHERE UserName = @CurrentUname

End`

HOW TO MODIFY THE CODE ABOVE?

**Second Update:**

```
If not exist (select UserName from aspnet_Users WHERE UserName = @CurrentUname)
Begin 
  UPDATE aspnet_Users SET UserName = @UserName,LoweredUserName = LOWER( @UserName)
WHERE UserName = @CurrentUname
End
SELECT 1;
else
select 0;
```

Comment: A ... ["unique constraint"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms191166%28v=sql.105%29.aspx)?

Comment: Is that really the best way to update it? Don't you just have to query the table to see if there already exists a user with that name, though - if you can write the query for the update, can't you write a SELECT query for that?

Comment: If the new username is already existing, I want to prevent it.

Comment: @pst This is probably the ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider's table - I'd be nervous about doing that because the default code might not handle the uniqueness exception gracefully

Comment: You need `WHERE UserName = @UserName` in the `if not exist()` too. But you also need to return success / failure from this snippet if you're doing the check in SQL.

Comment: There's a whole lot of context missing here.  What happens if the user exists?  Do you care about atomicity?  Is an application doing this?  If so, what makes you think side stepping the provider and running raw sql statements is the best way to get this done, given your fear of tampering with the table constraints?  Something smells funny...

Comment: See my second update. please.

Comment: Why not just do it through .NET?   You update SQL direclty and you risk breaking membership.

Comment: I assume something cares about that scalar recordset returned.  I would go with a return value or output variable.  Nothing technically wrong with what you have there, it's just a best practices/style thing.  It makes it obvious that the value kicked back is not a record set at all but rather a status.  The rest of my questions still stand.  Looks like it should do what you've asked so far.  Is there something else you want from it?  Still curious why you're not using the provider itself to do this.  It would be trivial to synchronize a check and update in .NET.

Comment: Blam, please post your code. There is one at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001491/is-it-possible-to-change-the-username-with-the-membership-api. But it still needs sql.

Comment: The SQL isn't the hard part nor the focus of the questions you're being asked.  You are talking about stepping outside of the provider entirely to do one specific action.  Extend the provider.  That's what it's there for.  You're still left with the question of why you're doing wacky things in a stored procedure instead of keeping it in the provider with all the rest of the business logic.  I tried dragging details out of you and you're resisting, so I'm confused as to what you want from us.

Comment: I don't have the permission to add unique constraint.

Comment: Then I apologize.  I did not realize the .NET API did not support that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In addition to @Icarus and @Pete M Replies. These are already Good/Trusted suggestion.

Alternative is, Can you use **[TransactionScope](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.transactions.transactionscope.aspx)** ?

**Pseudo Code**

```
using (TransactionScope scope = new TransactionScope())
{
    UPDATE aspnet_Users 
    SET    UserName = @UserName,
           LoweredUserName = LOWER( @UserName) 
    WHERE  UserName = @CurrentUname

    if((select count(userName) 
        From   aspnet_Users
        Where  userName = @CurrentUname) = 1)
    Begin
         scope.Complete
    End
}
```

The above approach keeps the independent `session of the request` under `Transaction` and keep it `isolated` from other request made by other users.

Comment: It seems to be different and inspired. Could you please add the entire code?

Comment: I have added Pseudo code. it's merely my Point of View. I hope you can convert it into actual code.

Comment: I guess that it should be scope.Complete() instead of Trans.Complete();

Comment: Please note that, This is the situation when you do not want to use the `Unique Constraint`.

Comment: @Love, major advantage of using this technique is a `TransactionScope` can span `multiple resources (i.e. multiple databases, or a database and an MSMQ server, etc).`

Answer (score 4):

Create a unique index on the username column.

Something like:

```
CREATE UNIQUE INDEX index_username
ON aspnet_Users (UserName)
```

Answer (score 3):

Place a unique constraint on the column in the database.  Then either check for an existing username before attempting the update, or catch the exception and handle it accordingly.

Comment: If doing the pre-check, it is important to use the appropriate transaction.

Comment: No, it is ASP.NET SqlMembershipProvider's table. I don't want do it in this way.

Comment: Good point.  There is no guarantee the desired name won't be taken by a second user in between checking for a pre-existing name and attempting the update for the first user.  A table constraint will still force the issue and yell at you, but that's a lot messier than doing the whole thing as an atomic transaction.

Comment: I don't understand why you don't want to add a constraint because it's a SqlMembershipProvider table.  If you want to ABSOLUTELY GUARANTEE uniqueness, constraints are the only sane way to do it.  There is always the trigger route.  It makes me feel dirty just mentioning it...  What is the whole story here?  Why are you doing this?  Maybe you should be looking at rolling your own provider?