# Accessing table aspnet_Users to update data

Tags: asp.net, sql, umbraco, membership

I was trying to use Chris S' solution for updating a username in aspnet_Users table - solution described here: [Is it possible to change the username with the Membership API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1001491/is-it-possible-to-change-the-username-with-the-membership-api)

It worked once then it stopped and now I'm getting an error message saying:

```
Exception Details: System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: Invalid object name 'aspnet_Users'
```

I am still able to create a user and his profile, just can't access aspnet_Users with my own query.

Creating a user and updating it works fine through library API, it means the table aspnet_Users exists, I just can't access it with my own query.

Any idea why this is happening?

Comment: Could you add your own query to the post?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had no aspnet_Users table indeed.
Instead in umbraco db the members were written to cmsMembers table and this actually I'm updating with new members' info.